# Find periods from timestamps in ordered table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Let's assume I have following table `CALLS` which is sorted by column `CALL` of type `TIMESTAMP`:

```
         CALL           TYPE  
 --------------------- ------ 
  31.10.2018 10:00:00   OFF   
  31.10.2018 11:00:00   ON    
  31.10.2018 12:00:00   ON    
  31.10.2018 13:00:00   ON    
  31.10.2018 14:00:00   OFF   
  31.10.2018 15:00:00   OFF   
  31.10.2018 16:00:00   ON    
  31.10.2018 17:00:00   ON
```

I want to write view that will find individual groups of calls with `TYPE=ON` and extract their start and end dates. As a result, for given example I get two groups:

```
         START                  END          
 --------------------- --------------------- 
  31.10.2018 11:00:00   31.10.2018 13:00:00  
  31.10.2018 16:00:00   31.10.2018 17:00:00
```

We should assume:

- Minimal count of group is 1, so we can get group that has the same start and end date
- `ON` rows are seperated by `OFF` rows but the first and the last row don't have to be `OFF` type

Is it possible to achieve that in Oracle 12c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  In this case, a difference of row numbers with aggregation does what you want:

```
select min(call) as start_time, max(call) as end_time
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by type order by call) as seqnum_t,
             row_number() over (order by call) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where type = 'ON'
group by (seqnum - seqnum_t)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run Oracle 12 then you can use also the [SQL for Pattern Matching](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/pattern.htm#DWHSG8956)

Would be like this:

```
WITH t (CALL, TYPE) AS (
    SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('31.10.2018 10:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'OFF' FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('31.10.2018 11:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'ON' FROM dual UNION ALL    
    SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('31.10.2018 12:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'ON' FROM dual UNION ALL    
    SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('31.10.2018 13:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'ON' FROM dual UNION ALL   
    SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('31.10.2018 14:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'OFF' FROM dual UNION ALL  
    SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('31.10.2018 15:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'OFF' FROM dual UNION ALL   
    SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('31.10.2018 16:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'ON' FROM dual UNION ALL    
    SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('31.10.2018 17:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'ON' FROM dual)
SELECT * 
FROM t
    MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
        ORDER BY CALL
    MEASURES
        FINAL MIN(CALL) AS CALL_START,
        FINAL MAX(CALL) AS CALL_END
    PATTERN ( CALL_ON+ )
    DEFINE
            CALL_ON AS TYPE = 'ON'
    );



+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| CALL_START                  | CALL_END                    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| 31.10.2018 11:00:00.000     | 31.10.2018 13:00:00.000     |
| 31.10.2018 16:00:00.000     | 31.10.2018 17:00:00.000     |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```